# How do I add a swap and comparisons counter in my code?

Tags: python, function, sorting, numbers, insertion-sort

For a list of numbers, I am trying to sort them in ascending order. At the same time, I need to add a swap and comparison counter to my output. For the most part, how do I add the incrementation in my code?
My code:

```
def insertion_sort(numbers):
    """Sort the list numbers using insertion sort"""
    # TODO: Count comparisons and swaps. Output the array at the end of each iteration.
    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        j = i
        # Insert numbers[i] into sorted part
        # stopping once numbers[i] is in correct position
        while j > 0 and numbers[j] < numbers[j - 1]:
            swap(numbers, j, j - 1)
            j -= 1
```

This is an insertion sorting method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split up the condition so you can separate the comparisons from the swaps.

```
def insertion_sort(numbers):
    """Sort the list numbers using insertion sort"""
    comparisons = 0
    swaps = 0
    for i in range(1, len(numbers)):
        j = i
        # Insert numbers[i] into sorted part
        # stopping once numbers[i] is in correct position
        while j > 0:
            comparisons += 1
            if numbers[j] < numbers[j - 1]:
                swap(numbers, j, j - 1)
                swaps += 1
            else:
                break
            j -= 1
    print(f'Comparisons: {comparisons}, Swaps: {swaps}')
```

Comment: How do I complete the function without the print statement and then later call the function and then print it?

Comment: Call it under "if __name__ == '__main__':"

Comment: You could have the function return the counts instead of printing them. Then you can do `comparison, swaps = insertion_sort(number_list)`