# How can I return how many times my list is compared and swapped using selection sort?

Tags: python, sorting, iteration, selection-sort

I want to return a list where after each iteration, in the list has the number of comparisons and number of swaps.
like an output such as this:
[[3,1], [2,1], [6,1]]
How can I achieve this?
Apart from knowing I should add a new [] and append it to that, i dont know how to get the number of comparisons and swaps. any help is appreciated!

```
def selection_sort(number):
    for pass_num in range(len(number) - 1, 0, -1):
        position_largest = 0
        for i in range(1, pass_num + 1):
            if number[i] > number[position_largest]:
                position_largest = i
        number[position_largest], number[i] = number[i], number[position_largest]

numbers = [90, 78, 54, 22, 73]
print(selection_sort(numbers))
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73243459/how-do-i-add-a-swap-and-comparisons-counter-in-my-code/73243494#73243494 for insertion sort. You should be able to do something similar in your code.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very experienced so, sorry if this is not helpful. You should use an global/static integer timer array for both # of comparisons and # of swaps. The comparison variable is incremented every time the conditional statement that makes the comparison runs, and the swap variable is incremented as a part of the code block that makes the swap. Both of these would be done at the active index in arrays parallel to the array being compared.

Comment: This is what I did but im only getting only the first index as output ([[4, 1]] when i should be getting [[4,1], [3,1], [2,1]]....why is that??
```
def selection_sort(data):
  swaps = 0
  comparisons = 0
  new_ = []
  for pass_num in range(len(data) - 1, 0, -1):
    position_largest = 0
    for i in range(1, pass_num + 1):
      comparisons += 1
      if data[i] > data[position_largest]:
        position_largest = i
        swaps += 1
    #data[position_largest], data[i] = data[i], data[position_largest]
    new_.append([comparisons, swaps])
    return new_
```

Comment: well, looking at it closer, It may be how you are trying to pass an array as an argument here. Is the function written to accept an array or a single number? If it is the latter, you may need to use a loop to process each item of the array(or list) in this way.